# LaTeX IEEEtran-de: Add URL access date

Tags: latex, bibtex, citations, ieee

I'm using the IEEEtran-de package and need to add the term

> Zugriff am: DD. MM YYYY

(URL access date) behind the URL. I tried to look up the IEEEtran-de.bst code and search for the relevant lines, but I'm pretty overstrained ...

Is someone familiar with this package and can help me out?

Comment: Rule of thumb: unless your bib style happens to produce *exactly* the output you are looking for, you are much better off with biblatex - that's much easier to customise